# Different Visual studio Build behavior when adding resource files as Link

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

The problem arises when adding resource files as Link.

When I build in my computer, I have these files compilation path-based. 
For example, if the Solution folder was XXXX. 
It is available by the path

`component/XXXX/DefaultLinkDataTemplate.xaml`

On the other computers
`component/DefaultLinkDataTemplate.xaml`

When checking the debugger is confirmed.

file .my assembly.g.resx 
in my comp

```
  <data name="resources/defaultlinkdatatemplate.baml" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>resources/defaultlinkdatatemplate.baml;ResourceTypeCode.Stream</value>
  </data>
```

in other comps

```
  <data name="defaultlinkdatatemplate.baml" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>defaultlinkdatatemplate.baml;ResourceTypeCode.Stream</value>
  </data>
```

This makes it difficult to work together on a project.

I  reload all Settings from other computer.
It did not help .

What settings in Visual Studio are responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Modify your code so that you look the file "DefaultLinkDataTemplate.xaml" in the current directory or else in the path of the executing assembly instead of hard-coding your path. If you could post some code, you could expect nicer answers

Comment: A lot of the developers of the project.
  Directories are used to highlight the functionality.Examples are meaningless for the problem in a different building a project on different computers.